# some weird things at boot

Tags: fedora, boot

[image]

When i installed Linux Fedora I only had thrice. no.1, no2, and Windows. Few days ago, others came from somewhere. I am not sure if I had done anything. For now, I am not getting any error. Can they affect?

Comment: Did you update with `yum` or `dnf`?

Comment: @NasirRiley `sudo dnf update` I did this.. and `sudo dnf upgrade` also. Sometimes I manually gets update when I power off from menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dnf update` installed a new kernel. The old ones are still there so that you can boot into them if needed in case there is a problem with the new one. The `0-rescue` was most likely there as well as it allows you to boot into Rescue mode in order to recover the system.

Other than the kernel upgrade and the upgraded packages that came with it, nothing about your system is going to function any differently. If you are sure that you don't need them, you can erase the old kernel versions and you'll just have the current which is at the top, rescue, and Windows 10.